# problem with $2.23$ Theorem Rudin's principles of mathematical analysis

Tags: real-analysis

> $2.23 $ Theorem a set $E$ is open if and only if its complement is closed.

I am a self learner and currently reading rudin's book and I have some question about this theorem (it is probably a stupid one because no one asked here before as far as I know) . what if $E$ is a closed subset of closed bounded subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ does this mean $E^c $ is open .

for example I drew this
[image]
since $S$ a closed bounded set it is contain its limit points and so $E^c $  contain some limit points then it is not an interior point of $S$!

Comment: this theorem is/has been mentioned rather a lot, actually. Googling "open iff. complement closed" (or "closed iff. complement open") generates a *lot* of resources, not just on this site

Comment: @FShrike I searched for 2.23
 Theorem  if you can give me a link to one of these question that would be helpful and I will appreciate that

Comment: Well, searching for "$2.23$" is a good try but googling for the actual statement itself ! is also a good try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $S$ is closed in the ambient space $X$ and $E$ is closed in $S$, $E$ is also closed in $X$. The theorem gives that $X\setminus E$ is open in $X$ and $S\setminus E$ is open in $S$. However, since $S$ is closed, there is no reason to expect (*and the theorem does not claim!*) that $S\setminus E$ is also open in the ambient space $X$.

The devil is in the notation "$E^c$", which I generally abhor. You are going to be much more accurate and less likely to err if you specify what set the complement is relative *to*.  Observe $S\setminus E$ is open in $S$ in your picture for the same reason that, say, $[0,1/3)\cup(2/3,1]$ is open in $[0,1]$. In the universe $S$ (analogous to $[0,1]$) there is no notion of the "outside" $X\setminus S$ (analogous to $(-\infty,0)\cup(1,\infty))$ and *all points of $S$ are interior to $S$* by a trivial inspection of the definition (all points, yes, even $0$ and $1$, are interior to $[0,1]$ in its subspace topology). Many notions in topology are *relative* and only a few are *absolute* (e.g. connectivity or compactness). Be careful with the relative ones.